# How to log exackly one object from fetched json data in react?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to log 1 object or 2 or as much as i want to be logged in console?
Im using simple data from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com (quite usefull for learning purpose) which every of object has unique id. 
For example:
I fetched data and rendered 200 posts on website, ok... but if i have a data which contains 100 logos or banners or layouts for website i want to render a specific logo or banner with unique id 30. 
So, how can I render only 1st, 2nd, 3rd or x post/posts from 200?


This is what i have now:
App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import './css/bootstrap.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Todos from './Todos';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            todos:[],
        };
      }

      getTodos() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({todos: data}, function () {
                    console.log(this.state);
                });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
      }
      componentWillMount(){
        this.getTodos();
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.getTodos();
      }
      
      render() {
      return (
      <div>
        <Todos todos={this.state.todos}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Todos.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class Todos extends Component {
    render() {
        let todoItems;
        if(this.props.todos) {
            todoItems = this.props.todos.map(todo => {
                return (
                    <TodoItem key={todo.title} todo = {todo} />
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Todo list from api</h2>
                {todoItems}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Todos.propTypes = {
    todos: React.PropTypes.array
};

export default Todos;
```

TodoItem.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class TodoItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li>
                <strong>{this.props.todo.title}</strong>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
TodoItem.propTypes = {
    todo: React.PropTypes.object
};
export default TodoItem;
```

@edit
Is there possible to filter mapped json data and find object depending on id and then render this object?

Comment: you want to render first `20 or x` data out of `200` data correct?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the example. I want to render 30th out from 200 posts, or 2 posts with id 20 and 35 out of 200. Something like that. I hope its better to understand. Sorry.

Comment: if you want get 1 data from 200 data you can use this url `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?id=30`

Comment: filter out the data on the basis of condition like render 30th data or data with id x, and pass that data to child component instead of all.

Comment: take look at libraries like lodash or underscore

Comment: @Rizal Sidik Its a bad idea to do like this, because I render only 1 object from data which contains only 1 object.
Mayank Can you make an example, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Slicing multiple items

You can use another state property, like **filterCount**, which can be either set by you manually, or you can trigger **setState** events from buttons e.g.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setFilter = this.setFilter.bind(this);
    this.state={
        todos: [],
        filterCount: 20 // Default value
    };
}

setFilter(count) {
    this.setState({ filterCount: count });
}

render() {
    const { todos, filterCount } = this.state;

    return(
        <div>
            ...
            <button onClick={this.setFilter(10)} />
            <button onClick={this.setFilter(20)} />
            <button onClick={this.setFilter(50)} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This will ensure that your component is rerendered each time when you change the count.

Now the second part, filtering the first x items.

The main way is to use [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Slice example:

```
render() {
    const { todos, filterCount } = this.state;
    const filteredToDos = todos.slice(0,filterCount);

    return(
        <div>
            ...
            { filteredToDos.map(todo => {
                return (
                    <TodoItem key={todo.title} todo={todo} />
                );
            }) }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Make sure you don't accidentally use **splice** instead of *slice*, because splice doesn't do the copy to a new array, but modifies the original one.

This example can be easily modified to support paging aswell. You could add a **currentPage** parameter to state, and just modify the slice line to slice the array based on which page you are.

Also, think about hard whether you need to use jQuery in your app. If you are using it only for convenience, then you are making a big mistake, as it is a hefty library that increases your bundle size considerably. Try to learn doing things the react way :)

Your ajax request can be done by using **fetch** api.

```
return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

If you don't need out of the box support for the older browsers, fetch api will be fine for last 2-3 major versions of modern browsers, including mobile ones. It can be polyfilled for older ones such as IE8 aswell.

Also, there are libraries like **axios** that are actually much smaller then jQuery if you need more options and support for all request types and headers.

Also, the fetch action itself, could be decoupled from the component to a separate **actions.js** file so it can be imported / used from multiple components in the future, or refactored more easily to support working with something like Redux if your app grows.

### Getting a single item

**Fetching single item from API directly** - suggested

If we are talking about performance, then the best way is to get a single item directly from API. Considering that this is a REST based api then the way would be:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/{id}

Rewriten for a fetch example with a template literal:

```
return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${itemId}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

This should also return a single object, not an array, so you should be able to pass it as a prop and use it immediately. IMHO, this is the best solution to the problem.

**Fetching all items from API, then filtering with filter**

Second option is to get all layouts, then filter the result which you can see in the example of: @mayank-shukla

Bottleneck of this method is that [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can return multiple results.

**Fetching all items from API, then filtering with find**

Third option is to get all layouts, then filter the result with [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Example is the same as filter, just change the keyword to find.

Find will return the first result in case of multiple ones.

**Fetching all items from API, then filtering by index**

Fourth option is getting all layouts, then filtering by index, e.g.

```
todos[itemId-1]
```

This will also work, but, you need to be 100% certain that backend will order the results in the array by their id. Also, index starts from 0, and your ids from 1, so this can be a source of major confusion.

Comment: Thanks for example, its good for rendering gallery, but like i said, if i have a json data with 100 layouts, its not gonna work with this code. I dont want to render first 20 layouts on webside xd Only 1 depending on id.

Comment: Sorry @Brunhilda for the confusion then. I have updated my comment to reflect the possible cases of filtering a single item, either from array or directly from API, which I would suggest.

Comment: One more think which i forgot. How can I set the object from fetch method to states in constructor so i can render it on page?

Comment: I've created a simplified code example here: https://jsfiddle.net/srL7r5t9/2/ . Also, it is not required to get todo items on both will mount and did mount. Considering that DidMount will always trigger only once, call getToDos there.

Comment: ComponentWillMount is most of all for testing other methods that i didnt included them here. Anyway thank for your time and help :)

Comment: I was glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing all the data to child component filter out the data on the basis of condition and pass that filtered data to child component.

Like this:

```
render() {
    //filter data of these ids
    let ids = [1,2,3,4];

    //filtered data
    let data = this.state.todos.filter(el => ids.indexOf(el.id) != -1);

    return (
        <div>
            <Todos todos={data}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If you want to pass first x data, the use [#array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and pass the result, like this:

```
render() {
    //filtered data
    let data = this.state.todos.slice(0, 20);

    return (
        <div>
            <Todos todos={data}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Instead of putting the filter part inside render you can do that after getting the response.